# Boxshadow appears behind other widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `Container` with a `BoxShadow` decoration at the top of a page, and below the `Container` is a `ListView` with a number of `Cards` in it. I want the top `Container` to have a drop shadow that appears in front of the items in the `ListView`, but this is what I get:

[image]

The drop shadow seems to appear behind the `Cards` instead of in front of it. This is the code:

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context, ChecklistModel model){
    return Container(
        child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red.shade200,
                        boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                            color: Colors.red.shade200,
                            offset: Offset(0, 10),
                            blurRadius: 10,
                            spreadRadius: 10
                        )]
                    ),
                    child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(''),
                    )
                ),
                Expanded(child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: _buildCheckpointListView(context, model))
                )
            ],
        )
    );
}
```

I also tried replacing the `Container` with a `Card`, but that didn't work either.

Comment: My case is the top widget. So i solved by put the `Container` as an `AppBar` and the `ListView` as the scaffold body. Therefore container shadows can appear normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because since you are using an `Expanded` widget inside `Column`, it is taking up all the available space on the screen and hence it looks like it is overlapping the `Container` but actually it's just overlapping the shadow.

Instead of a `Column` widget, use a `Stack` to show the `Container` above the `ListView`.
You can use `Positioned` widget to position the child widgets of the Stack.

But in this case, make sure you put the `Container` code after the `ListView` code so that it would always be on top.

**Example:**

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: _buildCheckpointListView(context, model)
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: 0.0, //To align Container at the top of screen
      left: 0.0,
      right: 0.0,
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red.shade200,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.red.shade200,
              offset: Offset(0, 10),
              blurRadius: 10,
              spreadRadius: 10
          )]
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(''),
        )
     ),
    ),
  ]
)
```

You can also wrap you `ListView` inside a `Positioned` widget if you want to provide a certain margin from top.

Comment: Nice! But the ListView definitely needs to be offset from the top, otherwise the top list item will be covered by the Container and thus inaccessible. Any idea how to achieve this if the height of the Container is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

Give a bottom margin to the container to introduce some empty space between container and bottom siblings. Like this :

```
        Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red.shade200,
              boxShadow: [BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.red.shade200,
                  offset: Offset(0, 10),
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  spreadRadius: 10
              )]
          ),
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(''),
          )
      ),
```

Comment: That does make it look better, but it doesn't really place the other widgets _behind_ the drop shadow, it just puts them _below_ it...

Comment: This maybe a little complex as in case of two overlapping widgets, the widget that comes below in the layout code overlaps the previous one. You can give a less than 1 opacity to list items.